# resizing row number column in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

IDE VS2010, c# .net 4.0

I need to resize columns of datagridview programmatically so I have written following code:

```
 internal static void ResizeGridViewColumns1(Control c, int incrColumn = 5)
    {
        DataGridView gv = c as DataGridView;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn currentColumn in gv.Columns)
        {
           currentColumn.Width +=incrColumn;
        }
    }
```

above code is working to resizing columns for datagridview, but I also wants to resize the width of gridNumberColumn (don't know technical term) (see red-boxed part).
please tell me how to resize this red-boxed part programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"redbox part" is a row headers area of `DataGridView`. There is special property for width of that area: `RowHeadersWidth`

so you need

```
DataGridView gv = c as DataGridView;
gv.RowHeadersWidth += incrColumn;
```